# Reverse a boolean based on a SQL CASE WHEN or IIF

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to reverse a boolean column based on a set condition in MSSQL (MSSQL Server 2017)

I have tried using IIF and CASE WHEN, but am encountering some syntax errors.

Method 1: IIF

```
SELECT
    IIF(Completed_Date > @EndDate AND Completed = 'True', --Conditions
    Completed = 'False', Completed) 
AS 
    Completed_Filter
```

Method 2: CASE WHEN

```
CASE WHEN 
    Completed_Date > @EndDate AND Completed = 'True'
THEN 
    Completed = 'False'
ELSE 
    Completed END
AS 
    Completed_Filter
```

The column field's Datatype is: [COMPLETED] [bit] NULL.

Running a straightforward filter query 
`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Completed != 'False'` gives no errors i.e. the boolean column works as it should.

However, I am confused as to why the above 2 code snippets result in syntax errors, which occurs at the equal sign in `Completed = 'False'`.

I am expecting to reverse the boolean from `'True'` to `'False'` in the event that `Completed_Date > @EndDate`, if not, just let the Completed boolean remain as is.

Would appreciate any help at all, thank you

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a `boolean` type.  I am assuming the type is really a string based on the syntax.  You should show the complete query and the syntax error.

Comment: your condition return string value and not boolean ..

Comment: What does `Completed = 'False'` mean inside the `IIF`/`THEN`? You can't assign an alias to a column inside an expression.

Comment: Aside: The typical way to flip a bit is with [Bitwise NOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-not-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). The truth table for your expression is a little off, so `~` isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This started out as a comment but soon got to big, so...

To expand on scaisEdge's and Sami's answers:

[`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is syntactic sugar for simple `case` expressions, with only one `then` and an `else` part. The remarks section of the documentation starts with this:

> `IIF` is a shorthand way for writing a `CASE` expression. It evaluates the Boolean expression passed as the first argument, and then returns either of the other two arguments based on the result of the evaluation.

The [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expression returns a single scalar value based on which condition is met.
It's documentation clearly states (again, in the remarks section), that it can't be used to control the flow of the T-SQL script:

> The `CASE` expression cannot be used to control the flow of execution of Transact-SQL statements, statement blocks, user-defined functions, and stored procedures.

Therefor, the problem in your code is this part `Completed = 'False'`, inside the case statement you can only write code that will return a single scalar value, but this code does not do that.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong

```
SELECT
    IIF(Completed_Date > @EndDate AND Completed = 'True', --Conditions
        'False', 
        Completed
        ) 
AS 
    Completed_Filter
```

Which is the same as

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Completed_Date > @EndDate AND Completed = 'True'
            THEN 'False'
            ELSE Completed
       END Completed_Filter
```

From the docs **[`IIF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

> Returns one of two values, depending on whether the Boolean expression evaluates to true or false in SQL Server.

Your boolean expression here is `Completed_Date > @EndDate AND Completed = 'True'` if this conditions is met it returns the first **value** and if not it will returns the second one.

There is no problem when you check with `'True'/'False'` against a `BIT` because it's valid, the string values `True` and `False` can be converted to bit values, 1 is `'True'` and 0 is `'False'`.

The problem is `Completed = 'False'` cause `IIF()` and `CASE` should returns a value, not a boolean expression.

See **[`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax)** expression and **[`IIF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function, where you can even find some examples provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an assignent  THEN complete = 'FALSE' but just select the value you need

```
CASE 
  WHEN Completed_Date > @EndDate AND Completed = 'True'
   THEN 'False'
   ELSE Completed 
END  AS  Completed_Filter
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CASE statement must return a string in every branch:

```
CASE 
  WHEN Completed_Date > @EndDate AND Completed = 'True' THEN 'False'
  ELSE Completed 
END AS Completed_Filter
```

Comment: [There is no string](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajPElu42BH4): `declare @Foo as Bit = 1; select SQL_Variant_Property( case when @Foo = 'True' then 'False' else @Foo end, 'basetype' );`. `'True'` and `'False'` are values of [`bit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). (From the OP: "The column field's Datatype is: `[COMPLETED] [bit] NULL`.")